# Key error for set_index of a pandas dataframe by list object

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, keyerror

I want to set the index of a pandas dataframe by a list which includes dates in a common format YYYY:MM:DD hh:mm:ss

```
index=df.index.tolist()

df2=df1.set_index(index)
```

the outcome

```
KeyError: '2011-06-21 00:00:00'
```

I tried to

```
df2=df1.set_index(str(index))
```

because of the backspace between date and time but the result was a KeyError for every single date in my index list.

Answer (score 1):

Add `[]` for nested list, else it looking for columns names:

```
df2 = df.set_index([index])
```